How to create a react native library wrapper over an ios framework file which has a dependency on other pods?
I'm new to react native and am trying to build a react native library wrapper over an iOS framework. This framework depends on a third party cocoapod (BSImagePicker). I tried to add this pod as a dependency in the podspec file and directly in the podfile but both don't work with the app crashing with
dyld[8161]: Library not loaded: "@rpath/BSImagePicker.framework/BSImagePicker"
My podspec file:
require 'json'

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, '..', 'package.json')))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name           = 'ReactNativeReader'
  s.version        = package['version']
  s.summary        = package['description']
  s.description    = package['description']
  s.license        = package['license']
  s.author         = package['author']
  s.homepage       = package['homepage']
  s.platforms      = { :ios => '13.4', :tvos => '13.4' }
  s.swift_version  = '5.4'
  s.source         = { git: 'https://github.com' }
  s.static_framework = true

  s.dependency 'ExpoModulesCore'
  s.dependency 'BSImagePicker'

  s.vendored_frameworks = 'TestFrameworks.framework'


  # Swift/Objective-C compatibility
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES',
    'SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE' => 'wholemodule'
  }

  s.source_files = "**/*.{h,m,swift}"
end

Podfile:
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...), which will be excluded. To fix this,
# you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` in `react-native.config.js`
#
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
#   }
# }
# ```
flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
if ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == '1' then
  # Explicitly disabled through environment variables
  flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
elsif podfile_properties.key?('ios.flipper') then
  # Configure Flipper in Podfile.properties.json
  if podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] == 'true' then
    flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"])
  elsif podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] != 'false' then
    flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"], { 'Flipper' => podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] })
  end
end

target 'readerexample' do
  use_expo_modules!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'BSImagePicker', :modular_headers => true
  config = use_native_modules!
  pod "GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition"
  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']
  use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work if enabled
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end

Would appreciate any help in knowing if I'm missing something!
I tried to add the cocoapod dependency through the podspec file and directly through the podfile and both end up with the app crashing on launch with these logs
dyld[8166]: Library not loaded: @rpath/BSImagePicker.framework/BSImagePicker
Referenced from: <36C62FDE-E2A2-35CD-8D1D-8C8F828147AC> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E0E3A1EE-4C7A-4D48-97F3-78F8DCF4EE75/reactnativegccardreaderexample.app/Frameworks/TestFrameworks.framework/TestFrameworks
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/BSImagePicker.framework/BSImagePicker' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/BSImagePicker.framework/BSImagePicker' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E0E3A1EE-4C7A-4D48-97F3-78F8DCF4EE75/reactnativegccardreaderexample.app/Frameworks/BSImagePicker.framework/BSImagePicker' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E0E3A1EE-4C7A-4D48-97F3-78F8DCF4EE75/reactnativegccardreaderexample.app/Frameworks/TestFrameworks.framework/Frameworks/BSImagePicker.framework/BSImagePicker' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/Frameworks/BSImagePicker.framework/BSImagePicker'
